# Code Inside my <script> are not being saved VS 2022

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[code not saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sv7P.png)
[but the .js file saves without any problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvzta.png)
[solution explorer if you guys need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMt1O.png)

so I've been trying out the bouncing balls assessment from MDN web docs but my Javascript doesn't work. I've tried both internal and external. All it says is that code is not saved every time I save it. (just the script portion).

Is this my issue or a vs 2022 issue?

**UPDATE** : SO I GUESS IT WAS JUST A BUG, CLOSING IT AND OPENING VS2022 WORKED.

Comment: What happens if you pull up that file in a different text editor, and attempt to save?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so another text editor like? I only have vs2022